# subclass of thread implementing Runnable interface

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, interface, runnable

It confuses me why a subclass of thread that implements a runnable interface doesn't force me to override the run method. Basically, when i create simple class that implements Runnable it forces me to override the run method. But when i made the ordinary class a subclass of thread, it didn't force me to override the class anymore. What's the logic behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a non-abstract class declares that it implements an interface, what that means is that the class must have a concrete implementation of every method that the interface defines, but those implementation methods don't have to be explicit in the class, they could be inherited from a superclass. In this specific example `java.lang.Thread` has its own `public void run()`, which subclasses inherit, so a subclass of Thread that implements `Runnable` doesn't need to add its own override to satisfy the compiler (though it probably does to actually be useful).

Comment: Does that mean that if i have a superclass which has a method with the same name with the method an Interface has that im going to implement in my simple class, the compiler wont warn me?

Comment: @ReubenJaMesAveñoGruta slightly more than the same _name_, the superclass method has to be compatible with the interface, so same name, same parameter types in the same order, and same return type (or a sub-type - if the interface method returns `Object` then it's valid to implement it with a method returning `String`, for example).

Answer (score 2):

This is because Thread itself implements run().

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

By default it does nothing. If we extend a Thread we implement this method so that it does something useful

Comment: That basically means, i have already overriden it by extending Thread class right? its not just shown by default.

Comment: You can extend Thread but not it does not mean you have overriden run()